# Help FullSimplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

How can you help FullSimplify? The first example is simplified but the second not (although it seems to be only a step away from the first example).

1.

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[x^2 + 4 y z > (2 - x)^2]
Out[1]= x + y z > 1
```

2.

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y z] > 2]
Out[2]= x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y z] > 2
```

Comment: Do you have any constraints on x^2+4 y z? What if this is negative?

Comment: You can check `Reduce`, possibly followed by `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the suggestions of the comments works:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[Reduce[x+Sqrt[x^2+4 y z]>2], {1>x>0,1>y>0,z>0}]

Out[1]= x + y z > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

let's rewrite it like this

```
x+Sqrt[x^2+4 y z]-2>0
```

then we can use `GroebnerBasis` to reduce the left side.

```
GroebnerBasis[x + Sqrt[x^2 + 4 y z] - 2, {x, y, z}][[1]] > 0
```

we get `-1 + x + y z>0`